# Can we record the instructions given to the cpu?

Tags: c++, memory, cpu

Given an initial state of a user driven program in memory, can we record the instructions given to the cpu, reload the program to it's initial state and playback the cpu instructions and have the program run as it did when the user was using it, without the user there?

I'm sorry if this question is badly written, or confusing.

Comment: What is the goal behind your question? Debugging? Testing? Simulation? All is possible but all solutions differ. If you give some more information, we can offer better help:-)

Answer (score 2):

If the user did interact with the program and you didn't store the history of inputs (or other form of interactions), the answer is clearly no.

A complete execution trace can be huge (1 Giga instructions per second...)

Answer (score 1):

**Most likely! It is possible to step through a program in a debugger going instruction by instruction. You'd have to also record the instructions in some form as well, though the program source or executable might work just as well.**

Some programs like to store things like networking logs or action logs in order to store the state of the program at some point in time. Databases may also store important information that can also be looked over when a program "fails." Something as simple as a log can be useful for recording input to a program.

For stepping through instructions, you should be able to use the `nexti` and `stepi` commands in GDB in order to execute instruction by instruction. We can also use `disassemble` to get the assembly instructions that should match-up pretty well with the individual CPU instructions. There should also be analogs in LLDB and MSVC's debugger.

And now, for my example of "state of a user-driven program in memory:"

[image]

It's the Windows Blue Screen of Death, but we can see that Windows actually creates a physical memory dump and also uses a debugger for the kernel.

It can be assumed that the physical memory dump can be used to figure out problems with the system at that moment in time and what caused the operating system to crash.

As for recording the individual instructions, the program executable itself should be sufficient to record what exactly happened, as a program's path of execution is clearly defined by the functions and operations it uses. Unless you're using using some sort of runtime meta-programming where you write your execution code at runtime, things should be able to be analyzed. And, even if you do write execution code at runtime, it should still be able to be extracted from a good memory dump, perhaps from inside a sandboxed-environment or through a meta-program to extract the state of the failed program.

Related: http://www.unknownroad.com/rtfm/gdbtut/gdbadvanced.html#STEPI

Answer (score 0):

It is a question on which system you are running. Tracing for debugging purpose is often possible, some CPUs have a special trace instruction for that. You can record each step of the program, included all data access. The idea is to find out later which program flow was executed and which data was accessed during which part of the program.

I have no idea that there is any tool which can read back such a trace and behave like the original program does.

To run a program with simulated user input is the other part but has nothing to do with your idea. Here the input(s) of the program will be run against some created or recorded data source. On most systems that will work without any problems. Especially on X-Windows based GUI systems it is quite easy to simulate the events and play them into the X Windows message pipe.

Another solution is to use a kind of virtual user. You can program or record the user interactions and run your program as every time. Such solutions can be found for windows and for linux systems. Wikipedia gives a long list of tools: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_GUI_testing_tools

Also take a look for sikuli http://www.sikuli.org/

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is NO. Assuming for the moment that your system has only one process, the system will still be responding to interrupts. Such interrupts can occur at any time. Replaying the handling of interrupts would be meaningless without the exact same external event occurring at the same relative time.